# Как проверить наличие подкатегории в категории?

Tags: python, django

У меня есть две модели Категории и Подкатегории. Хоче реализовать аккордеон, где тайтл - название Категории и когда  нажимаешь выпадают названия Подкатегорий, которые принадлежат к Категории.

```
views.py

def index(request):
    category = Category.objects.all().order_by('title')
    subcategory = Subcategory.objects.order_by('title')
    context = {'category': category, 'subcategory': subcategory}
    return render(request, 'app/index.html', context)

index.html

{% for i in category %}
    <div class="tab">
        <input type="checkbox" id="tab{{ forloop.counter }}" name="tab-group">
        <label for="tab{{ forloop.counter }}" class="tab-title">{{ i.title }}</label>
        <section class="tab-content">
           <ul>
              {% for j in subcategory %}
                   {% if ???? %}
                        <li><a href="{{ j.get_absolute_url }}">{{ j.title }}</a></li>
                   {% endif %}

              {% endfor %}
           </ul>
        </section>
     </div>
```

Как сделать эту проверку в блоке if?
Изменено:
Модель1  т.е Категории: Документальная литература, Публицистика, Художественная литература.
Модель 2 т.е Подкатегории: IT(Документальная л-тра), Бизнес(Документальная л-тра), Детективы(Художественная л-тра), Романы(Художественная л-тра) и тд.

[image: Тут выводятся все подкатегории, а надо чтобы выводились "дочерние"]

Тут выводятся все подкатегории, а надо чтобы выводились "дочерние"

Comment: {% if j %} не работает?

Comment: @Jack_oS работает но в итоге у меня все подкатегории которые есть в базе данных. А мне нужны только те подкатегории которые собтсвенно являються подкатегориями конкретной категории. Могу навести конкретный пример  если надо.

Answer (score 0):

Всего лишь надо было сделать такое

```
{% if j.category == i %}
```

Comment: ремокендую получше оформить ответ, и если это и есть решение - проголосуйте за свой же ответ, чтоб другие могли увидеть что проблема решена..

Comment: @finally свой ответ можно принять только через два дня

Comment: @finally "Голосование недоступно для собственных сообщений"